# Hover effect on LI from edge

Tags: html, css, hover

I have following HTML nested ul li structure, i wanted to achieve hover effect on each LI,(similar to current hover effect on li which has Capital A), it's child li should also hover from the starting of top most parent LI(below example as like Capital A li hover effect)

```css
ul { list-style: none; padding: 0; margin:0 }
li { margin:0; padding: 0; cursor:pointer}

.container > ul .items  {padding-left:1.5rem}

.items:hover {
  background:red
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<ul class="parent" id="Head">
    <li class="items"><a><span>A</span></a></li>
    <li class="items"> 
        <div class="group"><a><span>B</span></a> </div>
        <ul class="group-item">
           <li class="items"><a><span>b</span></a></li>
           <li class="items"><a><span>b</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="items">
        <div class="group"><a><span>C</span></a></div>
        <ul class="group-item">
          <li class="items"><a><span>c</span></a></li>
          <li class="items"><a><span>c</span></a></li>
          <li class="items">
             <div class="group"> <a><span>c</span></a> </div>
             <ul class="group-item">
                <li class="items"><a><span>c1</span></a></li>
                <li class="items"><a><span>c1</span></a></li>
                <li class="items">
                   <div class="group"> <a><span>c1</span></a> </div>
                    <ul class="group-item">
                      <li class="items"><a><span>c2</span></a></li>
                      <li class="items"><a><span>c2</span></a></li>
                      <li class="items"><a><span>c2</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
               </ul>
             </li>
           </ul>
        </li>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you mean something like `li:hover {background-color: red}` ?

Comment: @cloned Yes you are right

Comment: If this is what you want does that mean the question is answered? if not, please edit your question and add additional details.

Comment: If you look at the example. my hover effect is not specific to each content, i want get hover effect on individual li contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to only highlight the content then you should only target the content for your `:hover`

Here i targeted the `<a>` tag inside the `<li>`. If there can be other elements than `<a>`-tags inside your list elements then you also need to target them too. Or update the HTML to always wrap the content with a div with a specific class.

Changes I made to your code are:

```
li a {display: block}
li a:hover {background-color: red}
```

Keep in mind that it will probably better to use classes here, to not target every link inside a list of your site.

```css
ul { list-style: none; padding: 0; margin:0 }
li { margin:0; padding: 0; cursor:pointer}
li a {display: block;}

.container ul a  {padding-left:1.5rem}
.container ul ul a  {padding-left:3rem}
.container ul ul ul a  {padding-left:4.5rem}
.container ul ul ul ul a  {padding-left:6rem}

li a:hover {
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<ul class="parent" id="Head">
    <li class="items"><a><span>A</span></a></li>
    <li class="items"> 
        <div class="group"><a><span>B</span></a> </div>
        <ul class="group-item">
           <li class="items"><a><span>b</span></a></li>
           <li class="items"><a><span>b</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="items">
        <div class="group"><a><span>C</span></a></div>
        <ul class="group-item">
          <li class="items"><a><span>c</span></a></li>
          <li class="items"><a><span>c</span></a></li>
          <li class="items">
             <div class="group"> <a><span>c</span></a> </div>
             <ul class="group-item">
                <li class="items"><a><span>c1</span></a></li>
                <li class="items"><a><span>c1</span></a></li>
                <li class="items">
                   <div class="group"> <a><span>c1</span></a> </div>
                    <ul class="group-item">
                      <li class="items"><a><span>c2</span></a></li>
                      <li class="items"><a><span>c2</span></a></li>
                      <li class="items"><a><span>c2</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
               </ul>
             </li>
           </ul>
        </li>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, But i want that hover effect for child also start from edge of first Parent, as you see it on li of capital 'A'

here if you hover on example 'b', you see there is left side gap, i want to fill that gap with hover red.

Comment: Then you have to also remove the padding from the LI elements and add the padding to the individual a elements. Same as with the background.

Comment: No, I didn't downvote your question, I tried to answer it. If my answer is correct please accept it as the right answer.